# Which Chinese dialect group is the surname Kuok from?

Tags: topolect, names, surnames

Which Chinese dialect group is the surname Kuok from?

I assume it's a variant of the Mandarin Guo (郭).

Comment: Here's a famous 郭 -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Kuok

Comment: first of all, you‘re asking for “kouk” or, “kuok”?

Answer (score 2):

郭 ([*Kwok*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kwok), also spelled *Kuok*) is a Cantonese surname. It is cognate with the Mandarin surname 郭 (*Guo, Kuo*).